# keryx freezes when cancel pressed

Tags: 14.04, offline

I am trying to get Keryx up and running. However, I am running into a major error (I am using v1.0). I am also running ubuntu 14.04.

On the offline computer, when I press cancel download, the program does not change screens and stays at the download screen (it doesn't freeze pre say) and it doesn't stop downloadng.

From previous experience, do you have to wait a long time before it stops?  Is there some sort of work around so that I can install my dependencies? Or should I downgrade to 0.94?

Comment: I just released a new version of Keryx that may solve the problem. Download [0.92.5](https://launchpad.net/keryx/stable/0.92). The 1.0 release was never as well tested as we intended.

Comment: @mac9416 Hello, thank you for the update. It has nearly been a year since I asked this question and frankly, I completely forget what I was trying to do with it.

Comment: No worries, @philm!